# Digital Ocean: How to docker compose build in a volume

Tags: docker, server, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I have purchased volume for my droplet in digital ocean and when I do `docker compose build` it takes up space on my current setup and I am not able to build my images.

My current setup is on

```
`/dev/vda1       25227048 25191932     18732 100% /`
```

Full Ubunto is :

```
udev             2013884        0   2013884   0% /dev
tmpfs             404632     5672    398960   2% /run
/dev/vda1       25227048 25191932     18732 100% /
tmpfs            2023160        0   2023160   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            2023160        0   2023160   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda15        106858     3437    103421   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs             404632        0    404632   0% /run/user/0
/dev/sda       103081248    93980  97728004   1% /mnt/volume_lon1_01
```

**How do I build so it build on my new volume?**

```
`/dev/sda       103081248    93980  97728004   1% /mnt/volume_lon1_01`
```

Fail into error now:

```
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24
 Built: Wed Mar 21 23:10:01 2018
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: You should remove unused image and instance by command docker prune image , to free up the disk space. Then decide if you need to add more volumes. https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your new disk only for docker, you need to mount it in the docker base directory: `/var/lib/docker`.

But before doing it, you need to:

- Stop the docker daemon completely `sudo systemctl docker stop`
- Sync everything in the current directory to the new disk: `sudo rsync -aqxP /var/lib/docker/ /mnt/volume_lon1_01`
- Delete the old content: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*`
- mount the new volume to the right place: `sudo mount /dev/sda /var/lib/docker`
- Start docker daemon `sudo systemctl start docker`
- Check that everything works properly - you can check if you still have your volume listed `docker volume ls`, or some local images `docker images ls`, or if you can start a new container `docker run -ti alpine`
- Add the new mount definition into `/etc/fstab`*

You could also change the default directory of docker to use `/mnt/volume_lon1_01`.

If you want the second option, I recommend you to read https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux

*For modifying the fstab, if you are not familiar with, you need a few information: what is the filesystem used by the partition, its path and where you want to mount it
After that, edit the file `/etc/fstab` and check if a line already exist with the partition path (`/dev/sda` for you). If not, add a new line, if yest, just edit it for changing the mount path to the new one.

How to find the partition filesystem already mounted: `mount`
This will return one line par partition and you need to check the type of the partition.

Example: `rootfs on / type lxfs (rw,noatime)`, the partition type is `lxfs`

If you need to add a new line, it will be something like that:

`/dev/sda   /var/lib/docker       <fs type>   defaults        0 0`

Comment: that's fantastic. It would have been great to have command lines for each step in case anyone less knowledgeable could just run the commands. like how to stop docker daemon etc.

Comment: I didn't do it at first because a lot of command depends on the system, like on ubuntu it will not be the same as on CentOS, etc. What is the OS you use? I could add them for you :)

Comment: I am on Ubunto , I followed the step doing the second option but looks like there is bug in documentation :(

Comment: looks like systemctl start docker return empty. and you need to do sudo dockerd

Comment: Rigth, most of my command need to be prefixed by `sudo`, let me update it.

Comment: updated with my error that I am not struggling with

Comment: Is your docker daemon running? `systemctl status docker`
What do you have in the logs ? `journalctl -xe`

Comment: Can you post the error only for the docker daemon? `journalctl -u docker`

Comment: And which step did you execute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190398/discussion-between-chris-tarasovs-and-jmaitrehenry).